# Post request on Mongoose does not match with Get request

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

what is stored on my MongoDB Atlas does not match with my post request. Only the username is stored in my database, despite having a tweet and date in the post request and the schema. How do i get the tweet and date to show in my database? Thanks!

MONGODB Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const tweetSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  {
    tweet: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 140
    }
  },
  {
    date: {
      type: Date,
      required: true
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);

const Tweet = mongoose.model("Tweet", tweetSchema);

module.exports = Tweet;
```

express router:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
let Tweet = require("../models/tweet.model");

router.route("/").get((req, res) => {
  Tweet.find()
    .then(tweet => res.json(tweet))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});

router.route("/add").post((req, res) => {
  const tweet = req.body.tweet;
  const username = req.body.username;
  const date = Date.parse(req.body.date);

  const newTweet = new Tweet({
    username,
    tweet,
    date
  });

  newTweet
    .save()
    .then(() => res.json("Tweet added!"))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

post request:

```
{
    "username": "yourfatuncle",
    "tweet": "first tweet",
    "date": "2020-03-19T08:28:49.271+00:00"
}
```

get request:

```
 {
        "_id": "5e6f48d349a86510646354ae",
        "username": "yourfatuncle",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Comment: Try to change: `new Tweet({    username:username,    tweet:tweet,    date:date  })`

Comment: still does not work :*(

Comment: You have wrong schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const tweetSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    tweet: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 140
    },
    date: {
      type: Date,
      required: true
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);
```